# SSIS package deployment on SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I followed steps for package deployment on SQL given in MSDN and it was successful. But on deployment where I can see my package and I can schedule it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

[Where To Find Integration Services Packages in SQL Server](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Where-To-Find-Integration-Services-Packages-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

and

[Scheduling Package Execution in SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141701.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new job and schedule a package as a step.